# How do I change the case on every field in a mysql table in one call?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 27 varchar fields. I want to make all fields lowercase, but i want to do it in one short mysql call.

This does a single field:

```
UPDATE table
SET field = LOWER(field)
```

How do I do the equivalent of this (which doesn't work):

```
UPDATE table
SET * = LOWER(*)
```

Comment: +1 for a good question. I think the unfortunate answer is you can't do it with *one short query*. We'll see.

Comment: I like the way you think though - nice idea :)

Comment: What about `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table` and some server side language ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with your creative attempt `SET * = LOWER(*)` etc.

You can however do it like this:

```
UPDATE table SET
column1 = LOWER(column1),
column2 = LOWER(column2),
 -- etc, listing all text type columns
columnN = LOWER(columnN);
```

The reason there's no "shortcut" is probably because this pattern is so infrequently needed.

Comment: So I can't avoid typing out all 27 fields?

Comment: @T.BrianJones Btw. Having 27 columns means probably that your database is poorly designed.

Comment: @Tadeck - sadly, i'm dealing with a client who is giving me old database dumps where the db no longer exists, so i'm stuck importing their junk, and then cleaning it up.

Answer (score 0):

The consensus is that this cannot be done in a single mysql query.

Here is a super quick PHP script that does this for N fields (thanks for the idea @alex):

```
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS
        FROM table";
$results = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql);
while($column = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    $column = $column["Field"];
    $sql = "UPDATE table
            SET $column = LOWER($column)";
    $success = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql);
}
```

Comment: Your original question did not mention using a server-side technology. But yes, this is a potential solution, albeit aggressive.